# Visual Studio Regular Expressions Find/Replace not working as I expect

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am trying to match

```
EchoCancellation = Convert.ToBoolean(SendReceivePackets.GetNameValuePairsFromUnparsedReply(parsedReply["EchoCancellation"]));
```

and change it to:

```
EchoCancellation = Convert.ToBoolean(parsedReply["EchoCancellation"]);
```

There are about 3000 of these.

Here is my regex:

```
SendReceivePackets\.GetNameValuePairsFromUnparsedReply\(parsedReply\["{\w*}"\]\)
```

Visual studio says it can't find it. I don't believe Visual Studio, I think it is just lazy. :)

Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` should be `:w`.

Visual Studio uses non-standard regex.  Change your regex to

```
SendReceivePackets\.GetNameValuePairsFromUnparsedReply\(parsedReply\[":w"\]\)
```

Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Microsoft, just loves keeping things standardized huh. That fixed it by the way. Thanks!